# Shopify - How do you send two name attributes when user registers?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, shopify

I'm trying to add customer[tags][Size] shopify name attribute AND customer[notes][Size]. I want the SIZE to show up on both TAGS and NOTES under the customer's profile when they register for the first time.

It's currently (works) 1 name attribute:

```html
    
<label class="answer center"><input  data-fname="Small" value="Small" type="radio" id="CustomerFormSize" name="customer[tags][Size]"  required ><span>Small</span></label>

<label class="answer center"><input  data-fname="Medium" value="Medium" type="radio" id="CustomerFormSize" name="customer[tags][Size]"  required><span>Medium</span></label>
<label class="answer center"><input   data-fname="Large" value="Large" type="radio" id="CustomerFormSize" name="customer[tags][Size]" required><span>Large</span></label>
<label class="answer center"><input   data-fname="XL" value="XL" type="radio" id="CustomerFormSize" name="customer[tags][Size]" required><span>XL</span></label>
<label class="answer center"><input   data-fname="2XL" value="2XL" type="radio" id="CustomerFormSize" name="customer[tags][Size]" required><span>2XL</span></label>
 <label class="answer center"><input  data-fname="3XL" value="3XL" type="radio" id="CustomerFormSize" name="customer[tags][Size]"required ><span>3XL</span></label>
```

This sends a (3XL or whatever size) TAG to the Shopify customer in the admin. I want it to ALSO send it to the NOTES section of that Shopify customer in the admin section. So both customer[tags][Size] and customer[notes][Size]

Possible? Work around?

Comment: Impossible. if you need this then the rest of your code is wrong.

Comment: Why would you even need to do that?

Comment: Can't you just make 2 values out of 1 server-side?

Comment: Constructively, this seems like something I'd make a server policy.

Comment: I need it for shopify. The name="customer[tags][Size]" sends data to TAGS section of shopify. and the name="customer[notes][Size]" sends data to NOTES section of shopify. I would like to propagate those two sections with the same input/response.

Comment: you can just add more attribute, like `<input value="3XL" type="radio" id="CustomerFormSize" hello="customerINPUTWHATEVER" randomAttribute="HELLO_WORLD" name="customer[tags][Size]" required ><span>3XL</span></label>`

Comment: Well, browsers just don't provide that as a feature. There are JavaScript solutions and server-side solutions, lots of possibilities.

Comment: Do you have a reference to a Javascript that will execute this? @Pointy

Comment: @Konstantinos I believe with Shopify I have to use 'name' since thats how they structured it.

Comment: I am a Shopify expert.  Instead word your question to describe what your trying to achieve in Shopify and there is probably a lot more I can tell you.

Comment: Thank you but what is the reason you need it stored in notes?  you can only access notes through api and is for internal (shop owner) use, not customer.